# How to read implementors in Crate docs?

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand how to read crate documentation, in particular, how to read Implementors.

For instance, in a common crate such as TryFrom, a crate which allows you to convert between two types, implementors such as

`impl TryFrom<i8> for u64` or `impl TryFrom<isize> for u128` or
`impl TryFrom<NonZeroI16> for NonZeroI8`

can be seen at the bottom of the page

I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to read them

Using `impl TryFrom<i8> for u64` as an example, how does `TryFrom<i8>` relate to or interact with a `u64`? If I was going to actually implement `impl TryFrom<i8> for u64`, would I write it as `i8::try_from(a_u64_variable)` or `u64::try_from(an_i8_variable)`

Can someone describe in simple terms how to read these implementors?

[TryFrom Crate Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html)

Comment: Have you read https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html?

Comment: Using `impl TryFrom<i8> for u64` as an example, my key question is how does TryFrom<i8> relate to or interact with a u64? If I was going to actually implement `impl TryFrom<i8> for u64`, would I write it as `i8::try_from(a_u64_variable)` or `u64::try_from(an_i8_variable)`

Comment: It means that the `TryFrom` trait with the generic argument `i8` is implemented for `u64` (i.e. `Self == i64`). What does that means? That depends on the trait's declaration.

Comment: For `std::convert::TryFrom`, for example, you can see it has a method `from(value: T) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>`, substituting the generic arguments that means `from(value: i8) -> Result<u64, TryFromIntError>` so you can do `let _: u64 = <u64 as TryFrom<i8>>::try_from(0i8).unwrap();`

Comment: ^ This explanation was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `impl TryFrom<i8> for u64` as an example, the way to read this implementor is that it takes in an `i8` and intends to output a `u64`.

Answer (score 1):

The implementors section basically means: **the developers of this crate thought it would be nice if you could use this trait right away for common types, so we went ahead and added a bunch of implementations**. Thus there is no "If I was going to actually implement ..." about it. All these are already implemented and ready for you to use.